# MDX Exclude results where a value exists in a hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Please excuse me if I get some of the terminology wrong, I am relatively new to MDX/OLAP.

I have a dimension for determining ethical walls. The dimension looks like this:

```
Ethical Wall (dimension)
   --> Matter ID (hierarchy)
   --> Walled (hierarchy)
   --> White Listed Initials (hierarchy)
   --> Black Listed Initials (hierarchy)
```

The `[Walled]` hierarchy contains either true or false, depending on if the matter has a wall applied.

The White and Black list hierarchies contain user initials of people who either have or do not have access to a matter, respectively. Note, matters are either white listed or black listed, it is never a combination of the two.

I have been able to account for the no wall scenario and white list scenario relatively easily, but am having lots of issues with the black list scenario. This is the where clause I have come up with so far:

```
({
    (
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[True]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[XXX]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[]
    )
    ,(
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[True]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[]
        ,-{[Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[XXX]}
    )
    ,(
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[False]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[]
    )
})
```

Stripping down and representing it in a table the initial dataset, from which I am filtering down, looks something like this:

[image]

I want to select only the `Ids` to which the user with initials **XXX** has access. Applying the filter from above I get back all 3 `Ids`. The result set I am looking for is only `Id` `1` and `2`. The filer from above matches like this:

[image]

I understand *why* my filter is retrieving all 3 `Ids`, but I don't understand how to revise the middle portion of the filter to exclude `Ids` properly. This is the offending portion of the filter:

```
    ,(
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[True]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[]
        ,-{[Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[XXX]}
    )
```

How can I revise my filter to match on that data set like this?

[image]

Comment: so why include the middle tuple at all? if the middle tuple is selecting something you don't want to select then just delete that tuple from the set?

Comment: because the initial dataset I am filtering down from includes all the Ids, I'll edit the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the solution!!

Utilizing sets:

```
SET notwalled AS exists( 
       selectedmatters, 
       { 
         [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[False] 
       } 
     ) 
  SET whitelisted AS exists( 
       selectedmatters, 
       { 
         [Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[XXX] 
       } 
     ) 
  SET blacklisted AS EXCEPT( 
       selectedmatters, 
       exists( 
         selectedmatters, 
         { 
           [Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[XXX], 
           [Ethical Wall].[Black Listed Initials].&[] 
         } 
       ) 
     )
```

And then union:

```
UNION(notwalled, whitelisted, blacklisted)
```

No more crying for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simplify to this?

```
WHERE
({
    (
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[True]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[XXX]
    )
    ,(
        [Ethical Wall].[Walled].&[False]
        ,[Ethical Wall].[White Listed Initials].&[]
    )
});
```

Comment: My understanding is that having WHERE clause brings down the performance. Is that right?